# Using Java, How do I get get ddmlib FileEntry objects for something in the sdcard over adb programmatically?

Tags: java, android, adb, android-sdcard, ddmlib

I want to pull a series of files from the sdcard on an Android.
My problem is how do I get FileEntry objects for something in the sdcard?

```
 public void pull(FileEntry[] entries, String localPath, ISyncProgressMonitor monitor)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public FileEntry getEntry(String remotePath, IDevice device) {

    FileListingService listingService = device.getFileListingService();

    FileEntry entry = listingService.getRoot();    
    String[] segments = remotePath.split("/");

    for(String segment : segments) { 
        listingService.getChildren(entry, false, null);    
        entry = entry.findChild(segment):
        if(entry == null){    
            // throw new Exception();
        }    
    }

    return entry;    
}
```